# Is there a way to use existing cassandra(Along with data) with Janusgraph

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

I am trying to change the cassandra to Janusgraph with cassandra. 
But in my cassandra db, there is data.
How do I change to Janusgraph without data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way to do this.

This data set in Cassandra:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT name, alma_mater, missions FROM astronauts WHERE name IN ('James A. Lovell Jr. ','Fred W. Haise Jr. ','John L. Swigert Jr. ');

 name                 | alma_mater             | missions
----------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------
   Fred W. Haise Jr.  | University of Oklahoma |                                Apollo 13
 James A. Lovell Jr.  |       US Naval Academy | Gemini 7, Gemini 12, Apollo 8, Apollo 13
 John L. Swigert Jr.  | University of Colorado |                                Apollo 13

(3 rows)
```

looks like this in JanusGraph:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:janusgraph> SELECT * FROM janusgraph_ids LIMIT 4;

 key                | column1                                                                                  | value
--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------
 0x0000000000000003 | 0xfffffffffffec77f00059f18aaa71388306130376234306635303037382d38633835393061643933356531 |    0x
 0x1800000000000000 | 0xffffffffffffd8ef00059f18aadd69b0306130376234306635303037382d38633835393061643933356531 |    0x
 0xb000000000000003 | 0xfffffffffffec77f00059f18aad7bc90306130376234306635303037382d38633835393061643933356531 |    0x
 0x3800000000000003 | 0xfffffffffffec77f00059f18aacd5c50306130376234306635303037382d38633835393061643933356531 |    0x

(4 rows)
aploetz@cqlsh:janusgraph> SELECT * FROM edgestore LIMIT 4;

 key                | column1      | value
--------------------+--------------+--------------------------------
 0x0000000000003415 |         0x02 |                   0x0001043880
 0x0000000000003415 |       0x10c0 | 0xa072741e464c45575f4fce043480
 0x0000000000003415 | 0x10c2844800 |               0x8f00018e008080
 0x0000000000003415 | 0x10c2844c00 |               0x9981018e008180

(4 rows)
```

JanusGraph stores data much differently, separating out edges from entities, so that things can be queried in a graph native way.  Unfortunately, that will all have to be loaded via JanusGraph for it to be stored in that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to save via Janusgraph